# Overriding the property and renewing the property?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, terminology

On my sub class if I override the property, we call it property XYZ is overriding the property from the base class. What do you call if property is getting renewed by using `new` keyword? Renewed?

Comment: Can you edit your question to add `C#` tag if this is question about `C#` or `language agnostic` if this is a language independent question?

Answer (score 1):

This using of the `new` keyword as modifier is called `member hiding`.

From [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx):

> When used as a declaration modifier, the new keyword explicitly hides a member that is inherited from a base class. When you hide an inherited member, the derived version of the member replaces the base class version. Although you can hide members without using the new modifier, you get a compiler warning. If you use new to explicitly hide a member, it suppresses this warning.
>
> To hide an inherited member, declare it in the derived class by using the same member name, and modify it with the new keyword.

```
  public class BaseC
  {
      public int x;
      public void Invoke() { }
  }

  public class DerivedC : BaseC
  {
      new public void Invoke() { }
  }
```

For more information when to use `override` and when to use `new` keyword modifier you can read in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx) too.